# Grunt : htmlmin freezes -> which html file has errors

Tags: gruntjs

I use grunt to package my webapp.
Grunt freezes at htmlmin stage. I guess it's because one of my html files is malformed. But how can I know which html file is the cause of the freeze?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Grunt has several [options](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli) which can be utlized via the CLI.

[--debug](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#debug-d) and [--verbose](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#verbose-v) may help to reveal the problem file.

They are used as follows when running `grunt`:

`$ grunt --verbose --debug`

...or when running a specific task. E.g.

`$ grunt foobar --verbose --debug`

*(In the last example `foobar` would be replaced with the name of the task!)*

***Tip:*** Add a `.html` validation tool to your IDE to catch errors earlier in your workflow, or use an online validation tool. For example. [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)